# How to create 4 buttons in 2rows and 2 columns at center of the screen

Tags: android

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Settings"
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>          
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button03" android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button04" android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

please give suggestions,whether the code is right or wrong???

Answer (score 3):

So close!

First you need to put the whole table layout in the following view. This can be your root view if you want

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Then just ad to your table layout the following atribute:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

And finally change in the table layout `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content`"

Easy!

Comment: you can also add the below lines to the table layout

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"